# Unable to get properly item from localstorage when user is logged in

Tags: angular, typescript

Here I am getting `userid` from localstorage when user is Authenticated or logged in but that user id is getting as soon as I get logged in even I visit one page to another still not getting but when I reload the page then getting.

What might cause of this issue?

I have logo in header component, in that logo I have given router link and passed parameter as `userid`, that router only will work when user is logged in, if user is logged out then I  have created ng if method that time loggedin logo won't display and won't work. will display other logo.

But when the issue is I need to reload page, without reload page it is not getting

This is **header.html** code

```
<a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="" *ngIf="!this.authService.isAuthenticated()">
  <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="WAZ_logo">
</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/user-survey/{{Userid}}/{{name}}" *ngIf="this.authService.isAuthenticated()">
  <img src="assets/img/waz_home.png" alt="WAZ_logo">
</a>
```

this is **header.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  debugger;
  this.Userid = localStorage.getItem('user_id');
  this.name = localStorage.getItem('user.name');
}
```

I want to get userid as soon as user get logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you have a service that handles logging in and which you can query (instead of localStorage) about the info you need.

**BUT**

You could do it if you refactor your code as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
  // empty
}

get Userid() {
   return localStorage.getItem('user_id');
}

get name() {
   return localStorage.getItem('user.name');
}
```

Your **header.html** doesn't need any changes.

Comment: I am able to get value but not same time when user is logged, I have reload page then I am getting value

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga Have you tried what I posted? It should resolve your issue.

Comment: But here I want to remove id and user name from localstorage when user get logout

Comment: You can definitely do that. You could also do localStorage.removeItem('user_id'). Whatever works best for your usecase.

Answer (score 2):

The `localStorage` stores `strings` not `objects`. You will have to stringify the object and parse it out. Something like this

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
console.log(user.name);
```

You also may want to use a service to shared the data between the header component and the login component.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qj6kof
>
> https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Please can you give any clue

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga check my edits, I added a little example.

Comment: I am getting `userid` and `name` but  not as soon as user get login for that I have reload page then it is getting.

Comment: but  I was storing my token like this `// Store token
    storeWebToken = function (token) {
       localStorage.removeItem('web_token');
       localStorage.setItem('web_token', token);
    }`

Comment: Sounds like you need to update the values in the header from another component.  You can do this with Observables and sharing with a service.

Comment: ok if I want get userid from loacal storage as soon as user login so first what I need to for for   that

Comment: I would create a shared service that is used by both the header and login components.  The shared service will contain an observable of the user details.  Let the header value inject this service and subscribe to the observable.  After login, the login component update the new values in the service and the header will receive these new values. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga I put together a stackblitz as an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qj6kof

Comment: Thanks for creating stackblitz, I will implemented this if needed in future, it was nice